# Upgraded Azure subscription no longer deploys

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

I had free azure site and had that site migrated to a pay-as-you-go subscription. After correcting issues preventing code from successfully building on check-in by Disconnecting/reconnecting to TFS and renewing my certificates, I am able to get the checked in code to successfully build, but it will no longer deploy on build.

I am using TFS in the cloud (https://skilltraxx.visualstudio.com/) and have renewed my Integrate source control details for that site. Still no joy.

Re-linked the TFS project
[image]

updated some html:
[image]

Successfully checked in and built
[image]

And the changes are not copied over.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try dis- and reconnecting your TFS account (check this blogpost on how to do it: http://techmike2kx.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/tfs-preview-error403-and-windowsazure-continuous-integrationdelivery/ )

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue by creating a new pay-as-you-go web site, and moving everything over to it. Rather painful, but less painful than trying to get Microsoft to help out what should have worked in the first place. Since yours was the only answer I got, I'll credit you for the correct answer, which might have also worked, but added my own resolution in case it helps someone else.